# WP_query twice on a single taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I have a simple WP_query on a custom post and works fine:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post-type',
  'showposts' => 2,
  'location' => 'london'
);
```

but I want it to query two locations so used an array:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post-type',
  'showposts' => 2,
  'location' => array('london','paris')
);
```

but it only pulls in the last term. Is there another way that I should be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post-type',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('london','paris')
        )
    )
);
```

**Try this**